# Azure Devops Unable to Deploy the Azure Web App throws error

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment, azure-appservice

I am trying to deploy the Azure Web App in the Qa instance. I have created 3 different appsettings.json files with environment specific Client ID's in it

[image]

On the release pipeline for QA branch I am trying to use the test app service and set the settings like below

[image]

Release pipeline is all getting executed without any issues but when I try to access the application URL I get error like

[image]

Application ID is still pointing to the DEV one even though the appsettings.QA.json has different client ID of the Test App Registration where I set the reply URl and all correcctly.

I am not sure why my QA release pipeline is not using the ID's from the appsettings.QA.json. Can anyone please suggest me what is that I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Ensure that you have same URL configured as Redirect URI in azure AD for registered application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how the application picks correct appsettings.json -file into use. As it picks Appsettings.Development.json in QA-environment, check how the environment is set in QA-environment App Service. Perhaps there is an environment-variable with the value "Development" in App Service configuration and that should be set to "QA"?